# Server doesn't run after reboot

Tags: linux, reboot

I just rebooted the server, but doesn't go up anymore.

What can be the problem?

Server is RedHat and i used 'reboot' command from root ssh.

Comment: I think we'll need more information than that. What happens when you try to boot it?

Comment: well I logged as root and just typed 'reboot'. Then message "system goes down for reboot" showed and didn't go up after this.. that's it.

Comment: What does "didn't go up" mean?

Comment: Mean is down right now and I don't have access to server via ssh terminal anymore. It's remote server.

Comment: Does it have a BIOS password? is it LUKS encrypted? Do you have remote iLO/DRAC/any other remote control?

Comment: Do you know if it actually completed the reboot process? did you hear it beep or something.  Do you have physical access to the machine? If not, remote IPMI?

Comment: Found the problem. Was it between the server and the switch and the speed between. Need to set speed to 1000Mbits, duplex to full and turn off auto negotiation.

Comment: Why is downgrade?

Comment: Because your question is impossible to answer. There are hundreds of reasons why a server might not reboot correctly, it is impossible to know which is the case from the information you have given. All we know is what you tell us and all you told us is "did not reboot".

Comment: And with downgrade I magically will know what you mean. Isn't better to ask? That's way I will know what is wrong and will add more info to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have physical access to the machine or a KVM, hook up a monitor and observe the most recent output. It's possible that the system experienced a kernel panic or a generic boot failure and is standing by whilst still powered on. If nothing is displayed, try a cold reboot and check for any output during the POST and boot sequences